# What are whitespaces in binary files

Tags: python-3.x, binaryfiles, wc

I am writing a program in Python that is supposed to do the same as wc command in Linux (return number of lines, words and bytes of file passed to it). This needs to work when you pass it a binary file, but I keep getting a lot less words than wc outputs for the same file. What are whitespaces in binary files? `split()` works fine for text files because it splits by space, `\n` and `\t`.

```
with open(file_name, "rb") as f:  
    content = f.read()
    line_count = content.count(b'\n')
    words = content.split()
    word_count += len([x for x in words if x!=""])
open_file.close()
```

Comment: Assuming you're interpreting the binary file as ASCII (you need to interpret the bits as something that has whitespace in it, after all), you can get a list of all ASCII characters, codes 0 to 255, and intersperse them with `a`. So if the ASCII characters were `A`, `B`, and `C`, you'd get `AaBaC`. Then you see how much whitespace `wc` counts (be careful of an off-by-one error). Then, remove the last ASCII character and the interspersed `a` before it. If the amount of whitespace `wc` counts is one less, the next character to remove is a whitespace character according to `wc`.